# Set Vertical compression resistance priority to 749 for UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, constraints

[image]I am working on making a table view cell that has the following constraint relationships.

```
    -----------------
    |                |
    |  ____________  |
    |  |          |  |
    |  |__________|  |
    |                |
    |  ____________  |
    |  |label.    |  |
    |  |__________|  |
    |                |
    |  ____________  |
    |  |          |  |
    |  |__________|  |
    |                |
    |  ____________  |
    |  |label.    |  |
    |  |__________|  |
    |________________|
```

The subviews are as follows: (view, label, view, label).  I want the cell to dynamically resize with the two labels, for example, if the first label becomes taller, then the cell should become taller accordingly.  If both labels become taller or shorter, the cell should resize accordingly.  The two views should have a constant width and height.

If I start with a label I'm fine, a label and a view I'm fine, a label and a label, I'm fine, but if I have 2 labels and a view, as soon as I put the last constraint on the final label, auto-layout throws the error in storyboard (I don't have visible issues when running the app).

The problem is that I don't want to change the compression resistance because I don't want either of the labels to scrunch and I don't see why they would given the provided constraints.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you downvote, please say why.  I created this question sincerely.

Comment: Give size to fir property to your label by selecting your label and do cmd+sht+ = . And for tableview cell... in height for row you can return UITableView.automaticDimension. It will take dynamic height depending on the constraints.

Comment: "Give size to fir property to your label by selecting your label and do cmd+sht+ = " sorry not understanding this.

Comment: Sorry i meant size to Fit, and number of lines as 0

Answer (score 4):

Modify last label's bottom constraint to a constant with relation "Greater Than or Equal"

Your code should look like

[image] [image]

Hope this works

Comment: Wow. Why does that work? And how? This seems close to solving my issue. However, this does not solve my issue because I want the cell's height to be determined by its contents.

Comment: The constraints added by you are perfect. The issue is cell height. The cell height 
in xib / Storyboard is height than expected height. That's why this change worked.



You can give height based on your calculations. And then use


tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Comment: Sorry didn’t get you on this “is height than expected height.”

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have set the constraints properly, error on storyboards shows for even a tiny change in constraints like 0.5 pixels too. You can remove bottom constraints of last `UILabel` and reassign so that conflicting constraints can be rearranged. It will fix this problem.

**To get the dynamic cell size:**

1. Set the number of lines for both `UILabel` to 0.
2. Update relation of height constraints of both UILabel's from `=` to `>=`
3. Apply the following table delegate method in your code

   ```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
       return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
   }
   ```

**Use `UIStackView` to resolve the problem:**

Rather than adding constraints to all the views, you can take all the view's in a stack view and just assign the top, bottom, leading and trailing constraint to stack view and keep table delegate method. I think this will be more appropriate way.

Comment: If I remove the bottom label's bottom constraint and then reassign it, the error is still thrown.  Thank you for the attempt, but this does not solve my problem.